# Is there any option to view selected value from a table?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to know that is it possible to view only selected value from mixed values. Here's a sample sheet in that if we select `FRANCE` in `C1` then Column C must display only `FRANCE` ( like Filter) an eg is there in the right tab.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jdtrtdNQBsxiZt8FjvbaE9omCBs8x8vRgp0r2bc1_7c/edit#gid=13103082

Answer (score 1):

Try in E1:

```
=filter(c2:c,c2:c="FRANCE")
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a choice based on `E1` use

```
=filter(C2:C,C2:C=E1)
```

[image]

**OR** you may want your choice to be from `C1`

```
=FILTER(C2:C,C2:C=C1)
```

[image]